# PDO MySQL get records with previous date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

I've got a table with some columns. I want to filter some records using two of them, the one with INT type and second with DATETIME type. I'm using PHP PDO extension to connect with database and make some queries.

I'm trying to get the records from my table where datetime field is lower then given date, f.e.

```
<?php
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "fanpage` WHERE `flag_warning` = ? AND DATE(`update_date`) < ?", array(1, $date));
?>
```

This returns NULL, but when I paste the same query into the phpMyAdmin window it shows me proper records. What is the problem?

**Edit:**

Fragment from query function:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array())
{
    $result = array();
    $result['query'] = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result['query']->execute($params);
    $this->lastResult = $result['query'];
    unset($result['query']);
}
```

Comment: well can you show the actual prepare method in your library because this doesn't mean anything

Comment: Did you call $this->db->execute() ?

Comment: My `prepare` is an extension of `PDO::prepare` function.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the prepared statements at all

```
WHERE flag_warning = 1 AND update_date < CURDATE()
```

Comment: Also, when I remove the `update_date < CURDATE()` I get the results

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós - timestamp

Comment: Also curious thing is that when I use the same query on different table (but same columns) it works. Maybe some table settings or something?

Comment: everything you are curious of can be easily found out: just SELECT valuest you are trying to use in WHERE clause and see

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$sqlStatement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "fanpage` WHERE `flag_warning` = ? AND `update_date` < CURDATE()");
$this->db->execute(array(1));
$result = $sqlStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now $result has what you need.

Comment: Still not showing proper result, each time I get nothing.. When I try that query in phpMyAdmin or SQL console it shows me results..

Answer (score -1):

I've changed the column name to `date_time_upd` and it works right now, I think it's bug or something, maybe someone can explain that?

**Edit:**

Okay, I've figured it out. There was a fragment of code that checked for occurrence of the "UPDATE, DELETE OR INSERT" word in the query, and if there was a word like that the query result was not fetched. I've changed that to search for SELECT word, now everything is okay.

Comment: that's why these fragment checking facilities are evil

Comment: that's true, I know that right now, do you know any better choice?

Comment: yes, sure. To use Object oriented programming instead of trying to use one single function to do all the database operations in one call based on some unreliable magic.